# Encoded URL in links

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

How do I insert links that contain encoded URLs without SE misunderstanding it as markdown?

E.g.

```
http://tryapl.org/?a=R%20L%20C%u21901%201%200.00001%20%u22C4%20%28%u22A2%F7+/%29R%28L%F7k%29%2CC%F7%u2368k%u21900J%AF0.01%F7%u25CB1&run
```

fails:

[test](http://tryapl.org/?a=R%20L%20C%25u21901%201%200.00001%20%25u22C4%20%28%25u22A2%F7%20/%29R%28L%F7k%29%2CC%F7%25u2368k%25u21900J%AF0.01%F7%25u25CB1&run)

Answer (score 2):

[Like this](http://tryapl.org/?a=R%20L%20C%u21901%201%200.00001%20%u22C4%20%28%u22A2%F7+/%29R%28L%F7k%29%2CC%F7%u2368k%u21900J%AF0.01%F7%u25CB1&run)

```
[Like this][1]

  [1]: http://...
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: @NBZ When I follow the link in my post, it takes me to the same page that pasting the URL into the address bar takes me to. What problem are you having?

Comment: The characters do not seem to transfer right. The interpreter on tryapl reacts with an INVALID TOKEN. But not if I use the link in my answer. However, even that method doesn't always seem to work.

Comment: @NBZ What browser are you using? I'm using chrome, but your browser might have an idiosancratic issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
<a href="http://tryapl.org/?a=R%20L%20C%u21901%201%200.00001%20%u22C4%20%28%u22A2%F7+/%29R%28L%F7k%29%2CC%F7%u2368k%u21900J%AF0.01%F7%u25CB1&run">this</a>
```

[test](http://tryapl.org/?a=R%20L%20C%u21901%201%200.00001%20%u22C4%20%28%u22A2%F7+/%29R%28L%F7k%29%2CC%F7%u2368k%u21900J%AF0.01%F7%u25CB1&run)

Answer (score 1):

[What's not to work?](http://tryapl.org/?a=R%20L%20C%u21901%201%200.00001%20%u22C4%20%28%u22A2%F7+/%29R%28L%F7k%29%2CC%F7%u2368k%u21900J%AF0.01%F7%u25CB1&run)